# Can a parameter expansion work inside another parameter expansion?

Tags: bash

```
$ s=/the/path/foo.txt
```

we can extract by different criterion separately

```
$ echo ${s##*/}
foo.txt
$ echo ${s%.txt}
/the/path/foo
```

But if we want to extract according to both criterion at the same time,

```
$ echo ${${s##*/}%.txt}
bash: ${${s##*/}%.txt}: bad substitution
```

Is it possible to achieve the same goal, using parameter expansion only and without introducing a temporary variable?

Can a parameter expansion work inside another parameter expansion in some way?

Thanks.

Comment: I am asking about parameter expansion inside parameter expansion, whereas the link is command substitution inside parameter expansion.

Comment: @Tim: If you've seen from my first comment, you _cannot_ do it in `bash`

Comment: What is the desired result of your bad substitution?

Comment: @HaukeLaging looks like Tim wants just `foo`, i.e. the file name without the leading path components and also without its extension.

Comment: To understand recursion, one must first understand recursion.

Comment: @roaima that's correct.

Comment: @Hauke the desired result is `foo`.

Comment: @Tim the answer to the linked question addresses nested expansion in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No and yes. In Bash or standard shell the **first part** of the expansion has to be a *parameter* (i.e. a variable or a positional parameter, or one of the special parameters), not just any word.

[Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> The basic form of parameter expansion is ${*parameter*}. The value of *parameter* is substituted. The *parameter* is a shell parameter as described above  or an array reference.

The [text in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) similarly only mentions parameters.

You can use an expansion in the **other parts** of the expansions, since they can be arbitrary words. But that of course doesn't help in chaining manipulations of the same string (like in your example `${${s##*/}%.txt}`)

```
$ bash -c 's=/the/path/foo.txt; ext=.tyt; echo "${s%${ext/y/x}}"'
/the/path/foo
```

---

[Zsh explicitly supports](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) chaining, though:

> If a ${...} type parameter expression or a $(...) type command substitution is used in place of *name* above, it is expanded first and the result is used as if it were the value of *name*.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder what you meant by "chaining manipulations of the same string" in "doesn't help in chaining manipulations of the same string"?

Comment: @Tim, I meant the stuff in your example, like `${${s##*/}%.txt}`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for the extensionless filename component (i.e. `foo`) as a single operation, you can use an RE match to extract it from the path:

```
s=/the/path/foo.txt
[[ "$s" =~ (.*/)?(.*)\. ]]

echo "Got > ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} <"    # "Got > foo <"
```

I haven't found a way to strip the shortest unknown extension from a filename such as `foo.bar.txt` while still handling a filename component that has no extension at all (eg `foo`) unless you're happy to accept a compound expression:

```
[[ "$s" =~ (.*/)?(.*)(\.[^.]*)$ ]] || [[ "$s" =~ (.*/)?(.*) ]]
```

And if you do that it would be more efficient to perform two consecutive substitutions and just walk away:

```
s=/path/to/foo
f=${s##*/}
echo "${f%.*}"
```