# Vendor from MAC address (first three parts)

Tags: bash, string, replace

How you can get the first three parts from MAC address?

```
$ mac=11:22:33:44:55:66
$ vendor=${${mac//:/}:0:6}
bash: ${${mac//:/}:0:6}: bad substitution
```

`${mac//:/}` removes `:` and `:0:6` should get the first 6 characters?

or other way around:

```
vendor=${${mac:0:8}//:/}
bash: ${${mac:0:8}//:/}: bad substitution
```

Expected: `112233`. What's the correct syntax?

This works but needs two assignments:

```
vendor=${mac//:/}
vendor=${vendor:0:6}
echo $vendor
112233
```

Can you do this with one line with only bash?

GNU bash version is 5.1.0

Comment: [Use parameter expansion to modify output of another expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253606/use-parameter-expansion-to-modify-output-of-another-expansion)

Comment: _"Can you do this with one line with only bash?"_ -- sure: `vendor=${mac//:/}; vendor=${vendor:0:6}; echo "$vendor"`. But really, is it such a big issue to use the temporary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with `bash` you already have the solution, and it requires two assignments but if you just need the output you can omit the second assignment and directly output the result as `bash` yet doesn't support nested parameter substitution (maybe in the future it will).

```
$ mac='11:22:33:44:55:66'
$ vendor=${mac//:}
$ echo ${vendor::6}
```

Or use `cut` instead for short:

```
cut -d: -f1,2,3 --output-delimiter= <<<"$mac"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` as well:

```bsh
$ mac=11:22:33:44:55:66
$ echo "$mac" | awk -F':' '{ print $1""$2""$3}'
112233
```

About the nested parameter expansion, check this answer:

[Can a parameter expansion work inside another parameter expansion?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/415526/338177)